# psExec run file on shared folder (no C$ access)

Tags: windows, psexec

I'm in the following scenario:
my laptop is 20 miles away from a computer where I have a shared folder. I know the user/pass and I can login to this folder, where I see the files. So let's suppose this:

```
\\201.0.***.229\Moni
```

is the folder where I see the files. Ok, inside this folder I have a file called, Initializator.exe, and I want to run it on the remote computer (not on my laptop!), so I try:

```
psexec -i \\201.0.***.229\Moni Initializator.exe
```

and I get:

> Couldn't access 201.0.***.229\Moni: The system cannot find the path
>   specified.

if I try:

```
psexec -i \\201.0.***.229\Moni\Initializator.exe
```

psexec don't recognize my command and just show me it's banner with options. What I'm trying to do is possible?

PS: I have no permission to ADMIN$, C$ or anything else, only this shared folder.

Comment: That's not the usual syntax.  You should say `psexec \\201.0.x.229 c:\Moni\Initializer.exe` ; however, since you don't have admin access, psexec won't work anyway.  (You can't launch an application via a shared folder, that would be a huge security hole.)

Comment: Humm... I didn't knew this detail. Ok man, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no permission to ADMIN$, C$ or anything else, only this shared folder.

Then you won't be able to use PsExec on that computer.

From the author's article on [PsExec](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec) (highlight in **bold** is mine):

> As with many of the tools in the PsTools suite, PsExec's ability to run processes remotely requires that both the local and remote computers have file and print sharing (i.e., the Workstation and Server services) enabled and that the default Admin$ share (a hidden share that maps to the \windows directory) is defined on the remote system.
>
> [...] PsExec starts an executable on a remote system [...] by extracting from its executable image an embedded Windows service named Psexesvc and **copying it to the Admin$ share of the remote system**. PsExec then uses the Windows Service Control Manager API, which has a remote interface, to start the Psexesvc service on the remote system.

Answer (score 2):

Try this option

```
psexec -i -s \\Remote-Pc -u USERNAME -p ****** "locationoftheexe\Initializator.exe"
```

As the exe reside in the local machine, the exe will run and popup to the current user who has logged on.

Or else first copy the exe to the remote PC and then we can execute as previous cmd.

NOTE: psexec will not support UNC path ( network path "\" )

Comment: but use the following command to Use UNC path in PSEXEC

psexec \\Remote-pc -u USERNAME -p ***** cmd /c "\\server\software\setup.exe /S"

the above command will pass the string ("\\server\software\setup.exe /S") to the cmd.exe of remote pc and it execute..

PSEXEC does not support UNC but cmd.exe will support UNC path.